# Compile Typescript Without Losing node_modules path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a library for express called expresskit. The goal is to setup some organization standards for a node rest server so there is a specific way I'd like it to work.

For one, instead of having a tangle of `require` I want to use es6 explicit imports. Like this-

```
import ExpressKit from 'expresskit';

ExpressKit.start({
  port: 8000
});
```

I want to do this instead of `var ExpressKit = require('expresskit');` for a number of reasons. First, the IDE knows what the import is, while the require loses any intellisense. I don't want to use references because I want to avoid having `/// <reference/>` tags in all of my files. Second, with es6 explicit imports you shouldn't need namespaces/modules since the path acts as the namespace itselfs, like `com.org.foo.bar`. Here is an example of a route with expresskit-

```
import Route from 'expresskit/route';
import {Param} from 'expresskit/property';
import User from './';

export default class UserRouter {
  @Route('GET', '/user/:id')
  public static getUser(@Param('id') userId: number,) {
    return new User();
  }
}
```

You know exactly what's being used an where it comes from. There is no global-scoped objects or referencing via the `expresskit` namespace. The alternative would be something like this-

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/expresskit/expresskit.d.ts"/>

var ExpressKit = require('expresskit');
var Route = ExpressKit.Route;
var Param = ExpressKit.Param;

import User from './';

export default class UserRouter {
  @Route('GET', '/user/:id')
  public static getUser(@Param('id') userId: number,) {
    return new User();
  }
}
```

So the problem I'm having and the reason why I can't get the es6 explicit imports to work properly, is when the typescript is compiled via `tsc`. Javascript is built to a `bld` directory. Since you are referencing expresskit source via es6 imports, it is also building this to `bld`. The result looks like this-

```
  /
    bld/
      node_modules/
        expresskit/
          ...
      user/
        index.js
        router.js
      index.js
    node_modules/
      expresskit/
        ...
      express/
        ...
      body-parser/
        ...
    user/
      index.ts
      router.ts
    index.ts
    tsconfig.json
```

Now when I run the build project by running `node bld/index.js` I get the error-

> Error: Cannot find module 'express'

The reason for this is because expresskit as `bld/node_modules/expresskit/index.js` is calling `require('express')`, which it looking for express in `bld/node_modules/` when it's actual location is in `node_modules/`.

I don't want to copy everything from `node_modules/` to `bld/node_modules/` and if I did I think the usefulness of the library would be questionable.

What I'm about to try to do is compile to a single file using `systemjs` instead of `commonjs`. This will require a custom build script that injects `var System = require('systemjs')` to the top of the built file. But this may be the least invasive of my options. Is this the way to go?

**So how can I have my cake and eat it too?**

Comment: Why do you keep two `node_modules` directories? You can move `bld/node_modules` to `node_modules`. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: I don't. That is the result of building. I have managed to find a solution using sytemjs but it requires a custom build process. Only a few lines but I'm going to leave this open a little longer in search for a better solution before showing my solution.

Answer (score 1):

While I assume that OP has solved their problem after more than a year, for everyone how comes here later, here's how it works.

You just add `node_modules` to the `"exclude"` list in your `tsconfig.json` file. While you're at it, might as well add your build folder to not reprocess it every time and add more unnecessary files (resulting in folders like `bld/bld/bld/...`) and build time every time you compile.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { /* ... */ },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "bld"]
}
```